# is the behavior of WriteString surprising?

Tags: core-language

`WriteString["temp.txt","this string"]` returns `Null` but creates an open stream which is reused if you again `WriteString["temp.txt","this new string"]`. How is this behavior more useful than the obvious alternative, which is to have a separate  `AppendString` and to always close files after writing? The current approach seems bizarrely implicit to me. What is the motivation? Am I overlooking a convenience function that behaves as I expect? What is the expected approach to closing the opened stream in *this* case, since it is not returned?  (I realize it is available via `Streams[]`, but I assume that is not the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to what the motivation might be, except to say explicit `Open` and `Close` calls for low-level file writing seem to be pretty common in the languages I've used.

If you only want to write a single thing and close it immediately, I would recommend using `Export[]`.

If you want to use `WriteString`, you can just call `Close["temp.txt"]` and it will close it. You could even do:

```
file = "temp.txt";
WriteString[file, "this string"]
Close[file]
```

if you don't want to have to write your filename multiple times. Using `Close[]` does seem to be the expected method based on the documentation for `WriteString[]`.

Comment: Is being able to close with the filename string guaranteed? I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: @Alan The documentation says: `If there is only one stream with a particular name, the argument to Close can be "name". `

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, I read that. It does not define how "name" is set. For example, it does not say that the "name" will be the string used as the first argument to `WriteString`. Is that guaranteed?